# Dockerfile runs on Mac but won't run on Linux behind my proxy

Tags: perl, soap, docker

I have the following Dockerfile , for a container that runs just fine on my Mac, (I'm using docker-machine)

```
FROM perl:latest
RUN cpanm SOAP::Lite
RUN cpanm LWP::Simple
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
ENTRYPOINT [ "perl", "./doceng_purge_tools/bin/akamai_purge_pattern_generic.pl"  ]
# CMD /bin/bash
# docker build -t my_perl_purger_001 .
# docker run -t my_perl_purger_001 -pattern cd/Q14299_01 -server prod
```

However, when I run it using docker on my corporate network. I get a low-level SSL error.

Forgive my ignorance, but I thought a feature of docker is that I can be shielded from these platform gotchas.

Is there a way I can package this up, on my Mac, and just run the container in my Linux environment, behind my firewall?

I can supply more details about the SSL errors, if that helps.

Comment: Without an error message, it's going to be really hard to help. My first suggestion would be - check which versions of Docker you're running. It is designed for isolation, but doesn't cross CPU families well either.

Comment: Bear in mind your `RUN cpanm` is going to try and fetch from `cpan` which could be firewalled.

Comment: I have formulated this question in a clearer way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094606/perl-iosocketssl-pm-module-fails-to-initialize-in-my-docker-linux-environmen

Comment: Error output I was asked out error output on the stack overflow thread I mentioned above:DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2649: new ctx 54231968
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:562: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: ...22.0/Net/HTTPS.pm:69: local error: IO::Socket::IP configuration failed
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2682: free ctx 54231968 open=54231968
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2694: OK free ctx 54231968
Debugg: 500 Can't connect to control.akamai.com:443
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Wed, 19 Aug 2015 17:03:04 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response

Can't connect to control.akamai.com:443

Comment: Can you wget that url?

Comment: Yes. I got "unauthorized", but that's because I didn't put authorization in my wget.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094606/perl-iosocketssl-pm-module-fails-to-initialize-in-my-docker-linux-environmen , for my updated solution, I appended to the question there. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

> ... and just run the container in my Linux environment, behind my firewall?
>
> ```
> ...Can't connect to control.akamai.com:443
> ```
>
> ... but I thought a feature of docker is that I can be shielded from these platform gotchas.

If you run docker behind a firewall which prohibits connections to outside you can not expect to get a connection. Docker does not create some magic tunnel through the firewall but relies instead on the existing network, same es it relies on the existence of the CPU, RAM and storage. Proper network is just another resource you need to provide for your docker image.

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't it. It wasn't a firewall problem. It turned out, the low-level Perl SSL code wasn't working, so I had to alter my Perl environment to use another code path. And thanks for letting me know about the magic tunnels , or lack thereof :-)

Comment: @egilchri: Since I'm the maintainer of IO::Socket::SSL I would be curious to know what the underlying issue really was. I can not get this information from this nor from your other question, only that you claim you forced the use of IO::Socket::SSL while linking to the solution which describes forcing Crypt::SSLeay (i.e. the other one).

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say that I forced the use of Net:SSL.  I don't know why IO::Socket::SSL wasn't working for me. But what I found out was that my machine inside my firewall that was working, was using Net::SSL. So I decided my task was to coerce my machine built by Docker to use Net:SSL as well. It could well be user error, that I'm not able to get IO::Socket::SSL working. All I know is that the connection was hanging.

Comment: @egilchri: Where there any proxies involved in your setup? Because proxy support with IO::Socket:SSL was only fixed with LWP 6.06 (about a year ago).

Comment: Yes, there are proxies involved in my setup.  I'll need to check the version of LWP that was being used.